# Convergence of a Series of Random Variables tail end behavior

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

To show for a given $\omega \in \Omega$,  that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n(\omega)<\infty$ can I just show that the tail sum sequences goes to zero. What I mean if I can show for 
$$S(n,n^{'})=\sum_{j=n}^{n^{'}}X_j(\omega)$$
$$\lim_{n,n^{'} \to \infty} S(n,n^{'})=0$$

My idea is that if the tail sums are decaying to zero  then the addition to the  series towards the end is trivial and the series settles  down to a value. Will this work?

Comment: Yes, by definition of convergence ($\mathbb R$ is complete). If $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$, then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges if and only if $\forall_{\varepsilon > 0} \exists_{M > 0} \forall_{n>m>N}$ you have $\varepsilon > |S_n - S_m| = |\sum_{k=m+1}^n a_k|$. But, I'm just curious due to probability tag. Are you indeed interested in convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k(\omega)$ for a given $\omega \in \Omega$ or just say for almost sure convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k$ ? If the latter, there are many other "tricks" to establish almost sure convergence of series of random variables.

Comment: @DominikKutek Did you mean that the partial sums are cauchy. As to the probability aspect, I know of using either a kolmogorov's 3 series for truncated r.v or by borel cantelli. Is there any other